# CloudWatch graphed metric not showing data, but query returns results

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, amazon-cloudwatch, autoscaling

I created an CloudWatch alarm that monitors the AutoScalingGroup's **GroupDesiredCapacity**.
However **CloudWatch is not able to retrieve the metrics** from it, metric does not plot anything on the graph. When I create an **Graph with SQL query**, by clicking on the metric it **plots** the **correct** data.

I think I have missed something in my configuration, but I am not sure what exactly.

**CloudWatch graphed metric**

[image]
[image]

**Graph with SQL query**
[image]
[image]

I ensured that I have the right IAM privileges to get access the EC2 metrics.

In my Terraform configuration I enabled the metrics on the auto_scaling_group

**aws_autoscaling_group:**

```
resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "example" {
  
  ...


  enabled_metrics = [
    "GroupMinSize",
    "GroupMaxSize",
    "GroupDesiredCapacity"
  ]


}
```

**metric_query:**

```
metric_query {
    id = "asg_size"

    metric {
      metric_name = "GroupDesiredCapacity"
      namespace   = "AWS/AutoScaling"
      period      = 120
      stat        = "Average"
      unit        = "Count"

      dimensions = {
        AutoScalingGroupName = aws_autoscaling_group.cluster_autoscaler[each.key].name
      }
    }
  }
```

Can anyone please help me identify what I may be missing in my configuration that is causing the graphed metric to not show any data?

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Have you created the graph (not the sql) via Terraform? If yes, please try to create it via CloudWatch directly. In my experience CW sometimes silently fails without visible user error.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I think I figured it out. The unit = "count" so it measures the quantity of something, rather than a rate or other unit of measurement.

Comment: As @Augunrik suggested, it can be really difficult getting the dimensions and other settings for CloudWatch metrics correct in Terraform, because it can be incredibly difficult finding clear documentation on what exactly you should specify for those values. And if you get it wrong, you just get an empty graph instead of an error message. The best method to debug this is to create the same metric manually in the CloudWatch UI, which fills out all those settings for you automatically, and then look at what is different in your Terraform created resource, and the manually created resource.